# Justifying $\mathbb{Z}$ is a commutative ring with 1.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am having trouble justifying $\mathbb{Z}$ is a commutative ring with 1 under multiplication and addition.

Book defines a "ring with 1" as a ring $R$ that has the identity if there is an element $1a=a1=a$.

The additive inverse of the ring element $a\in R$ is denoted as $-a$. Is it enough to state,

Do I just show that $a+(-a)=0$ for any $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ for addition? How can I justify it for multiplication?

Comment: It sounds this is one of those sorts of problems where you have to get right down to the formal definition of what it means to be an integer, at least to properly, rigorously justify it. What definition you're meant to use has probably been communicated to you prior in your course - not that there aren't other, equivalent formal definitions, but I'm, for example, looking at the [Proof Wiki definition](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Integer/Formal_Definition) and I don't remember the construction quite like that. xD

Comment: You simply need to prove that all axioms of a commutative ring with 1 hold.

Comment: If I understand the source of confusion correctly, it is distinguishing between the additive identity, 0, and the multiplicative identity, 1.

Only addition is required to have inverses: the additive inverse of $a$ is $-a$.

For multiplication, an element in a ring need not have a multiplicative inverse.  Indeed, $3$ has no multiplicative inverse in the ring of integers.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Clearly one should define $\mathbb Z$ as the free (unital) ring on zero generators...

Answer (score 1):

You can't justify it for multiplication.   You have stumbled onto the fact that $\Bbb Z$ is a ring but not a field (it lacks multiplicative inverses).

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring and not a field, so you don't have to find multiplicative inverse if that's your concern.

**what is $\mathbb{Z}$ ?**

Define the following equivalence relation $\operatorname{E}$ on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ :
$$(a,b) \operatorname{E} (c,d) :\Longleftrightarrow a+d = c+b$$

- Setwise, $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} /\operatorname{E}$. The idea behind the scene is that the class $\overline{(a,b)}^{\operatorname{E}}$ represents $a-b$, eg $-5$ is $0-5$ or $1-6$ or $2-7$ etc.
- Addition is defined componentwise : the sum of $\overline{(a,b)}^{\operatorname{E}}$ and $\overline{(c,d)}^{\operatorname{E}}$ is 
  $$\overline{(a,b)}^{\operatorname{E}} + \overline{(c,d)}^{\operatorname{E}} 
  := \overline{(a+c,b+d)}^{\operatorname{E}}$$.
- Multiplication is a bit trickier. The product of $\overline{(a,b)}^{\operatorname{E}}$ and $\overline{(c,d)}^{\operatorname{E}}$ is
  $$\overline{(a,b)}^{\operatorname{E}} \times \overline{(c,d)}^{\operatorname{E}} :=
  \overline{(ac + bd,ad + bc)}^{\operatorname{E}}$$
  Can you check that these operations are well defined (this is often the trickiest part)?

**What do one need to check?**

You need to check that

- $+$ and $\times$ are associative.
- There is a neutral element for addition (try $0:=\overline{(0,0)}^{\operatorname{E}}$).
- $+$ is commutative.
- Every element has an additive inverse (hint : $-\overline{(a,b)}^{\operatorname{E}} = \overline{(b,a)}^{\operatorname{E}}$).
- There is a neutral element for multiplication (try $1 :=\overline{(1,0)}^{\operatorname{E}}$).
- $\times$ is distributive over $+$.
- $\times$ is commutative.

If you edit your question to include the proofs of each of these points, I would be glad to help you.